# Cannot reach Linux server with web explorer using public IP address

Tags: linux, networking, server

I set up a Linux server and I can't access its `public_html` directory from the web explorer using the public ip address.

However, I can access the server using SSH with the public ip address.

I am not sure what is wrong.

Comment: Well, is an http server running at all? If so, have you opened the port in the firewall?

Comment: Yes please add details on your web server and configuration

Comment: What information can I provide you? What commands should I run on linux to output useful information that would be helpful?

Comment: I forwarded port 80 on my router and 3306 since my mysql work bench isn't connecting either. Not sure if that is the correct move. I also realized that even when I use a local address, mysql work bench can't connect either.

Comment: @arkascha I am running apache2 on my server. Yes, it is running. I can access the webpage via a local address.How do you open the ports on the fire wall in linux server?

Comment: That depends on the distribution you installed. They all bring frontends to the `iptables` based network filter typically used inside Linux based systems. I suggest you take a look at some "getting started guide" for the distribution you chose or look into your systems software package management system. you should be able to find an installed firewall frontend or install such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check httpd service is running or NOT

```
$ sudo Service httpd status
```

If not then Start Httpd

```
$ sudo service httpd start
```

Check either Port 80 is not allowed by iptables service(Firewall)
To open port 80 I do this:

```
$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

Save

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/iptables save
```

Comment: It tells me for the following:
$ sudo Service httpd status
Service command not found

sudo /etc/init.d/iptables save
command not found

Comment: its debian{ubuntu} or rpm{centos} ?

Comment: Its debian Ubuntu server

Comment: try $ sudo service ufw stop

Comment: It now tells me "ufw stop/waiting"

Comment: your iptables service is stopped  now check you are able to access public_html ??

Comment: I can access it using my local ip address but not my public ip address.

Comment: what is error when you are trying to access useing public ip ?

Comment: This webpage is not available.

Comment: You are able to access public_html  using local Ip means apache2 is running and listening port 80
iptables service is also stopped then also you are not able to access using public ip addess.
Something wrong in **PORT FORWORDING** please check it

Comment: You mean port forwarding on the router?

Comment: You're right. I forgot to port forward port 80. I thought I forwarded it already. Silly.... Thanks so much.